# How to make the content of a span wrap onto the next line in an embedded <a>

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation:

```
<li style="width:100px">    <!--display:block-->
    <a href="...">          <!--display:block-->
        <span>Link text Which is longer than 100px</span><!--display:inline-->
    </a>
</li>
```

At the moment the long text is expanding beyond the outer limits of the `<li>`  but I would like it to wrap onto a second line.

How can I achieve this with css?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for.. ? http://jsfiddle.net/q33dj/

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that property.  Stick it in an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) to achieve this.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q33dj/)

```
span {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css

```
ul > li {
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all; /*see this property in a colorful box*/
  background: gold;
}
```

Now the html

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">
      Link text Which is longer than 100px
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">
      Link text Which is longer than 100px
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And you will see the magic :). One tip, work more with css than the line of html.
Bye